# Invalid JSON - Cannot see why

Tags: json

The following JSON string comes back as invalid in several formatter tests. I cannot figure out for the life of me what is wrong!

```
{
"draw": 122, 
"recordsTotal": 1496, 
"recordsFiltered": 1496, 
"data": [["11315","1403","John Doe","Parking Pass","-","Hyundai Sonata - Grey ABC 123   ","09-01-2016 2:00 AM","09-01-2016 7:00 AM","-"]] 
}
```

https://jsonformatter.org/ is saying:

> Parse error on line 5: ...,"Parking Pass","-","Hyundai Sonata - Gr
>   -----------------------^ Expecting 'STRING', 'NUMBER', 'NULL', 'TRUE', 'FALSE', '{', '[', got 'undefined'

https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/ says:

> Error:Invalid characters found.[Code 18, Structure 28]
>   and highlights the line "Hyundai Sonata - Grey ABC 123    ",

What the heck am I missing?  I dont see any invalid characters anywhere. If I paste it into Notepad++ its not showing anything but "CRLF" on the line breaks.

Comment: Copy/pasting that JSON works fine for me?

Comment: It's valid for me in jsonformatter.org and jsonlint.com. Try copy pasting the one you posted.

Comment: You're right, when using what I pasted its valid. There must be something different when I copy/paste thats removing whatever is invalid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After checking, it turns out that the value, which was being returned from a database, had a tab in it. I created a function to strip out any non ASCII chars and its working fine now

Comment: Yep, the tab is present in your question markdown (but not in the HTML rendering). An unescaped tab is not valid in [JSON strings](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7159#section-7). Can you fix and/or report the bug in the database code that generated it?